# Multiple queries regarding Docker Multi Stage Build process

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, devops

I am new to **Docker** and got confused in couple of things. I have few queries as well. Please find them below. I would be happy if these queries got resolved.

**Question 1:**
In multi-stage builds, how does docker identify the artifacts of a stage? Because I saw in many articles, people say `COPY --from=0 src dest` will copy the artifacts from the last build stage. I mean where have we explicitly defined that you need to copy the artifacts from this folder? What defines the `build output`/`build artifact` of a stage?

```
# Stage 1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

# Stage 2
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Core3Api.dll"]
```

- **Q2** - Does `COPY --from=build src dest` copy files from a previous build or the image?
- **Q3** - Normally copy has two parameters, one is the source and the
  other is a destination. Above we have three parameters,
  `--from=build` `src` `dest`. How does this copy works?
- **Q4** - Do we need to set `WORKDIR` in every build stage? Because I
  think every build stage executes in a new isolated context? OR it
  uses the same context?
- **Q5** - Where does Docker stores previous build's image when it moves to
  next stage?

All my questions are interrelated, that's why I clubbed all into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker builds *images*; each image consists of a filesystem plus some additional metadata.  Within the context of a multi-stage build (Q5) each `FROM` line starts a new image build, and the result of these image builds are totally normal images; you can see them (probably with a `<none>` name) in `docker images` output.  Similarly, because each build stage stars `FROM` the context of some previous image, (Q4) you do need to repeat `WORKDIR` in every stage where it matters (but since each stage is in an isolated build context, different stages don't necessarily need the same working directory).

The Dockerfile `COPY` command (Q3) can take options, in much the same way as you can `cp -r from to` in a normal shell.  The `--from` option (Q2) names an image; it can be an earlier build stage `FROM ... AS name` in the same Dockerfile, or it can be an arbitrary other image.  (Q1) It copies from whatever the filesystem result of the image build is.

```sh
FROM ... AS build
WORKDIR /build
RUN ...
COPY ...
# An image is created that's effectively a snapshot here

FROM ...
WORKDIR /app
COPY src dest                       # from the build context
COPY --from=build /build/dir dest2  # from the "snapshot" point
COPY --from=0 /build/dir dest3      # from the first image in this Dockerfile
COPY --from=busybox:latest /bin/busybox dest4  # from another image
```